# Flow network with correlations

Tags: algorithm

I have flow network problem similar to the [Maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

But in my network, there is special kind of node: the flow of its outlets must keep a given ratio.
For example, in a network where we have:

```
 Edge    Capacity
 A->B    10
 C->B    3
 C->D    6
 B->E    12
```

The flow on edge `C->B` and `C->D` must keep a ratio of `1:2`.
I'm not sure if my problem could still be solved by the classic Maximum flow algorithms. Any ideas how can I solve it? Could anybody please give me a guide for the direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at linear program solvers. This problem is certainly expressible as an LP, and the ratio constraints destroy total unimodularity, so it seems unlikely that any of the specialized algorithms for combinatorial optimization would be of much help.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your reply. Yes, the problem could be solved by LP. Actually my current solution is using LP. But we are not satisfied with the speed of LP. We may need to solve many of these graphs in a short time (millions or even billions in minutes). So I'm thinking of implement the specialized algorithm to replace the current LP method. However, I cannot prove if this is feasible currently in theory, so I'm coming here for guides.

Comment: @ricetest Are you using a solver with support for extracting a network simplex subproblem?

Comment: Hello David, I'm using the open source LP lib lp_solve currently, and modelling it in a normal LP problem. I was not aware of network simplex until you mentioned that. Would you please give me some recommendations on the LP solvers? And I will search for the network simplex in LP to learn. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ricetest If you can get your hands on CPLEX or Gurobi (commercial software), then that might be something to try.

Comment: Hello David, is there a budget option or even freeware you recommend? Our current budget may not allow such solvers. Thank you very much for your guidance!

Comment: @ricetest Try the evaluation versions, at least, to see whether their secret sauce has anything that helps. Failing that, are you open to very good approximate solutions? I could try to think of a specialized interior point method.

Comment: OK, thank you David! I will try it later. Actually, I'm still thinking whether it could be solved with modified Ford-Fulkerson method or something faster than LP. I need to investigate more these days.

Comment: @ricetest I'm not sure that I'm going to have time to investigate, but there are these approximation algorithms for multicommodity flow that work via what's now called the multiplicative weights method. Essentially they average a bunch of shortest paths together to make a flow, recomputing the edge weights after each path to account for the increased congestion. I'm wondering if it might be possible to change the weights in such a way as to drive the outflows to being approximately proportional where needed.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your guide. But, it seems multi-commodity problem not similar with my problem. Because the special nodes in my problem (named "splitter") has a fixed split ratio; the flow must keep this ratio even the capacity may not be fulfilled. I think in multi-commodity problem, no matter what weights we assign, the capacity will always be fulfilled regardless of the split ratio. However, I will leave this post open for some time and investigate more. Thanks!

Comment: @ricetest It wouldn't be using the algorithm as a black box -- it would be reconfiguring the math to approximately enforce your constraints.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your advice. Yes, I meant the multi-commodity is not usable directly, the weight and split ratio constraint are very different. I will investigate more if there is room for modification or is there any other algorithms.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your advice. Yes, I meant the multi-commodity is not usable directly, the weight and split ratio constraint are very different. I will investigate more if there is room for modification or is there any other algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solved.
Think of the [Ford–Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) algorithm. It basically says that while you can add more flow, add it.

In your case, you run this algorithm, but every time you want to add flow to `C->B` or `C->D` (or any edge under constraint), you:

1. Check your special constraint to verify that you can / how much flow you can add to both edges.
2. Add the flow from #1 to both edges simultaneously (in the same step).

Comment: Hello shapiro, thank you for your reply. But I don't think Ford-Fulkerson could correctly solve this problem. In this example, the result of Ford-Fulkerson depends on which edge we select first. If we we select edge A->B first, then the capacity left for edge C->B will only be 2. And the total flow will be 16. But If we select C->B or C->D first, the total flow will be 18, and this is the actual max flow.

Comment: A. Can we get a diagram of the actual example? B. The example of Ford-Fulkerson was to demonstrate that you could use some algorithm and perform a change in it to accommodate your constraints. If Ford-Fulkerson doesn't work, try one of those mentioned in the page you mentioned.

Comment: A. I'm not dealing with a specific diagram, but trying to implement an algorithm to deal with this kind of problem. I think the example in the original post is OK for demonstration. We can setup a more complicated example with more this kind of nodes and normal nodes mixed.
B. I'm investigating other algorithms other than Ford-Fulkerson currently. But the doubt of whether they are capable of solving my problem could not be cast off easily. I will be back later when I learned more.